# Nginx Form-base Authentication

Tags: authentication, passwords, rest, nginx

I want to have nginx in front of my Tomcat and to act as a authentication gateway. So if request is not authenticated in will be redirected to login form that will also be stored on nginx. nginx will collect user/password from login request and pass it to RestAPI for validation.

I don't want to store login form on Tomcat and give any access to not-authenticated requests to Tomcat.

Is this setup possible? (I don't have a problem to write some code to call this RestAPI from nginx)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to route requests based on whether or not they have a particular header set. The tricky bit comes from determining whether it's set correctly.

Most web authentication goes something like this: you request a page. The application sees that you haven't sent along a session cookie, and redirects you to the login page. You login, and get a session cookie. You request the first page again, the server reads your session cookie and validates it, then sends you the page.

The tricky part for you is dealing with validation. You say you don't want *any* unauthenticated requests to make it to your application, but that means that not only do you need to verify that the client has sent authentication, but that it's *valid*. Otherwise, it's easy for an attacker to just set an arbitrary value for their authentication header and get access to your application.

Usually I'd say you should implement access controls in the application. It knows context about the various pages it serves up, and having authentication and authorization bundled directly with the app makes it harder for an attacker to bypass the auth layer. However, based on your question, I'm assuming this isn't a feasible solution for you (because it's a third-party app you can't modify, for instance).

Nginx is really good at proxying http requests. It is not particularly good at implementing application logic. I would have nginx proxy **all** requests to an auth application, and that application then proxies authenticated requests on to the main application. This will be much more straightforward than trying to implement auth-checking in nginx.